# Violates the following Content Security Policy directive: *** in Shopify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, shopify

I made a custom App for Shopify. But I got the below error when I set up the application AWS EC2.

> Refused to frame 'https://***.com:2053/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src app.myshopify.io *.shopifyapps.com *.myshopify.io *.myshopify.com https://* shopify-pos://*".

Curiously, when I use Ngrok on the EC2, it works well. On the other hand, when I use the original domain, it doesn't work and I get the error. I have already set up an SSL with Certbot. I confirmed to connect to my domain directly, not via shopify app. I made it referred to this site: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react.

I have been researching it for a week tho, I have no clue to resolve it. Do you guys have the same experience and do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67277614/content-security-violation-in-shopify/72226377#72226377

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSP includes `https://`. According to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#port-part-matches) this does not mean HTTPS on arbitrary ports, but only on default port 443.

Your custom app instead uses `https://...:2053` which matches the allowed protocol but does not match the allowed port. When using ngrok both protocol and port match since ngrok is using the default port 443.

Comment: Unbelievable! I could do it! I finished the long journey. I appreciate you a lot bro!